# Wix Upgrade Issue

Tags: wix, installation, upgrade, wix3.8

Here is a scenario that i want to implement.but i don't have good idea to implement this.

let's say that someone get a installer and install it today. tomorrow someone get a new installer with the higher version number want to install it on the same PC. the installer with the higher version need to do the following things.

1. there should have a dialog to let user choose which modules to
   upgrade.
2. update those modules base on the user's selection, but
   don't delete other modules that user don't select.

i have tried use `Majorupgrade` element to implement this. but it always delete the modules that we don't select. see below:

for example .in the previously version we selected **feature A** and **feature B** to be installed.  and in the new version we only choose **feature A** to update.  the **feature a** was updated successfully , but it deleted the feature B at same time.

Is there anyone have a good idea to implement this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure users want this complexity and have the knowledge to make such decisions?

Comment: yes,i am sure. Actually i have a idea to implement this. but it was not a good one. see below:
just set attributes "Permanent" of  the components in the feature A and feature B to "yes". when select feature A to update. use a customer action to delete all the files that related to the feature A . then the installer will install the missing files.

Comment: Hmmm... you have to read about _Minor Upgrade_ then you install it via console (u can't go thru UI - not supported for minor upgrade) then read about [REINSTALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371175(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute - as you can read, you should be able to set what features to be upgraded. I never do this, so i can't help you with example code, sorry. Example to show how to upgrade all: `msiexec /i setup.msi REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus` [REINSTALLMODE and its attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371182(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You could start with a separate line of MSIs for each module. Assigning matching version numbers across the set might help users make decisions about upgrades. A custom EXE UI with WiX's DTF could present the upgrade/leave it/install it now options.

Comment: This is not the way Windows Installer works and you are going down a path that will cause plenty of issues. You can do the same general thing by having a conventional major upgrade and your components are actually just features in a feature tree that the user chooses during the upgrade. You must put all the "modules" in all your MSIs anyway, because the MSI you use for major upgrade is also a fresh install for new clients.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a separate line of MSIs for each module. Assigning matching version numbers across the set might help users make decisions about upgrades. A custom EXE UI with WiX's DTF could present the upgrade/leave it/install it now options